# some local files missing on remote after git push

Tags: git, push

I did a git push from my local to bitbucket. This is a Django project. 3 files from my project level directory are still present on my local but missing from the remote on Bitbucket: manage.py, README.md, and runtime.txt.

Why did these three files not get pushed? How do I fix it? And going forward, how do I have confidence in the integrity of my pushes and pulls?  If you know Django, you know manage.py is a pretty important file. .gitignore only has venv, staticfiles, and .pyc. And yes, I did do git status afterwards:

```
(cannon)malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/cannon/jamf$ git status                     
On branch master                                                                   
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.                                    
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be your files do not in the version control so firstly you should add manage.py, README.md, and runtime.txt files in version control using the **[git add](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-add)** command and then **`commit & push`** again. and make sure these files are not ignore by `.gitignore` file.

Comment: This was the problem. For reasons I can't remember or imagine, at some point they were added to gitignore. All that is now fixed. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 3):

try `git add --all` and then commit and push again. It will push all changes you made in all files.

Basically:

`git add --all`

`git commit -m "add all"`

`git push`